# Convert an undefined number of columns in rows in Unix

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have a file which looks as follow:

```
1 genA genB
2 genC genA genS genY
3 genM genC genF
...
```

And I would like to have the following output:

```
1 genA
1 genB
2 genC
2 genA
2 genS
2 genY
3 genM
3 genC
3 genF
...
```

Is there any way this can be done in unix using awk, sed or similar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Awk:

```sh
awk '{ for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) print $1, $i }' input.txt
```

This basically means "for each line, for each non-initial field, print *the first field (`$1`) and that field (`$i`)*.

Output:

```
1 genA
1 genB
2 genC
2 genA
2 genS
2 genY
3 genM
3 genC
3 genF
```

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -ae 'my $num = shift @F; for (@F) {print "$num $_\n"}'
```

`-a` is enables autosplit mode. This splits each line into the array @F.

Answer (score 5):

Some more `perl` alternatives:

```sh
perl -lane 'print "$F[0] $_" for @F[1..$#F]'

# assuming digits can occur only in the first column
perl -lape 's/(?<!\d) /\n$F[0] /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^((\S+) \S+) /\1\n\2 /;P;D' file
```

Replace a second space by a newline, the first value in a line and a space. Print/delete the first line and repeat.